# How to animate a div only once?

Tags: jquery

i have two div(`action,action2`) which will animate if the scroll amount is above 100.what i want is `action2` to be animating from 40% of right and bottom then animate to 30% of right and bottom then again 40% of right and bottom. i tried with the below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var t = $(document).scrollTop();
        if (t > 100) {
            $('#action').stop().animate({
                right: "50%",
                bottom: "50%"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
            $('#action2').stop().animate({
                right: "40%",
                bottom: "40%"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
            $('#action2').stop().delay(800).animate({
                right: "30%",
                bottom: "30%"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
            $('#action2').stop().animate({
                right: "40%",
                bottom: "40%"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
        } else {
            $('#action').stop().animate({
                right: "0",
                bottom: "0"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
            $('#action2').stop().animate({
                right: "0",
                bottom: "0"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
        }
    });
});
```

this doing `#action2` div animate multiple time.i want it to animate once as in code like from 40% to 30% then 40% that's it. What wrong in this code. Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BtX8v/

Check this [step1](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=jpalw4&s=5) for 2 and 3 see comments i don't have reputation to post more than two link and images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this line

```
$(document).scroll(function()
```

with this one

```
$(document).one("scroll", function()
```

the `one()` will only run the event once as opposed to `scroll()` or `on()`.

[documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

---

I didn't notice you had a condition for your animate within your event. In that case, try this (add a variable to keep track of whether it has ran, then run based on that):

```
var done = false;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var t = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (t > 100 && !done) {
        done = true;
        $('#action').stop().animate({
```

---

With more clarification on the issue, it seems you are just looking for different functionality based on if the div's are already up or not. Try something like this:

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BtX8v/6/)

```
var actionsUp = false;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var t = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (t > 100) {
        $('#action').stop().animate({
            right: "50%",
            bottom: "50%"
        }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
        $a2 = $('#action2');
        if (actionsUp) {
            $a2.stop().animate({
                right: "30%",
                bottom: "30%"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce", function () {
                $a2.animate({
                    right: "40%",
                    bottom: "40%"
                }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
            });
        } else {
            $a2.stop().animate({
                right: "40%",
                bottom: "40%"
            }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
        }
        actionsUp = true;
    } else {
        actionsUp = false;
        $('#action').stop().animate({
            right: "0",
            bottom: "0"
        }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
        $('#action2').stop().animate({
            right: "0",
            bottom: "0"
        }, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
    }
});
```

Comment: This won't work, he wants it to scroll only once when `t > 100`

Comment: no when ever the scroll happen this animation should occur.am asking about the `#action2` div animating multiple time after i stopped scrolling.

Comment: @smerny just a small syntax error with the variable. As of now, it will still run the animation every time.

Comment: @smerny whenever scrollTop is higher than 100 let the animation happen i'm not bothering that But when i scroll #action2 should go to 40% 30% 40% then it should stop.if again i scroll down this whole sequence should happen.

Comment: @smerny interesting in firefox only am getting this issue not in chrome.

Comment: getting tough...There too one problem.can you recognize anything

Comment: @smerny ya that is another problem i'm telling now when i see it in chrome.Glad you pointed it.

Comment: @smerny is anything wrong with queue like stop() or delay() functions?

Comment: @smerny While posting this question i had one problem but now am trialing many problems like when we scroll greater than 100 small box doing the sequence two or three times(in firefox) after that if we scroll less than 100 small box should immediately come to 0 right but it not coming in chrome.

Comment: @smerny while we scroll greater 100 at that time itself small box should come to 40% then 30% then again 40%.

Comment: @smerny can you come in chat i don't have reputation to begin. if you don't mind

Comment: @rram, when i try to move to chat it tells me that you don't have enough.

Comment: @smerny am seeing immediately 30% and 40%. Also if i scroll even more 100 small box alone animating not big box.this shouldn't happen right.

Comment: @rram, according to your code/comments, it looks like you want **if less than 100** both divs go to 0,0. **If greater than 100**, big div goes to 50% (or stays there if its already there), small div goes 40-30-40... if it was already at 40, then it would 30-40. This is what the latest jsfiddle i provided does. If this is not what you expect, please let me know exactly what you expect it to do.

Comment: @smerny yes correct,  but not if it was 40 then it shouldn't have to animate 30-40

Comment: @rram, is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/BtX8v/6/) finally what you are looking for?

Comment: @rram, That just seems to show 40-30-40? Can you explain what is wrong with the jsfiddle I put up here http://jsfiddle.net/BtX8v/6/

Comment: @smerny check step 1 it should come to 40  first then 30-40 now it is coming in 30 first then 40 in the fiddle.it should come as you said but not coming like that

Comment: @rram, do you mean when it moves from the bottom then? like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BtX8v/7/

Comment: @smerny check this [jelly](http://jsfiddle.net/xzyKL/) fiddle this is what i expected

Comment: @smerny the difference between question and this jelly fiddle is question doing the small box animation 2 times but in jelly fiddle it is happening one time. I  can't able to tell why it is happening that way. if possible if you find difference between them explain me that.am accepting your answer.if you like jelly fiddle please update that as answer. i will be available after 10hours from now for discussion.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, the only difference between this one and the last one i posted is that there is a 1000ms pause when before moving to 30%. This pause is caused by the fact that it's "moving" to 40% first when it's already there.